# Devons nous proposer un message de bienvenue ? / Should we offer a welcome post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, new-users

J’ai débarqué sur StackExchange via TeX.SX. Une habitude qui règne là-bas est d’accueillir les premières interventions avec le message « [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) », lien compris, accompagné d’éventuelles remarques sur les usages ou de suggestions d’amélioration.

Il me semble que cela permet aux-dits nouveaux de bien comprendre le principe sans se devoir tout réexpliquer dans les quelques 500 caractères qu’autorisent les commentaires. D’autant que, en 500 caractères, on est vite un peu sec.

Pensez-vous qu’en faire autant ici soit une bonne idée ?

---

I discovered StackExchange through TeX.SX. They have the habit of welcoming new users by commenting “[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)” (with the link), possibly with remarks about how the sit works or how to improve their first posts.

I think that helps new users understand the site principles without having to explain it all over again every time in under 500 characters or so, especially as souding warm and welcoming is quite hard under those circumstances.

Do you think implementing this here would be a good idea?

Comment: [No, for the sake of everything that is holy, please, no.](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/welcome-page-needs-more-welcoming/3772#3772)

Comment: While I agree with you against its systematic use (i.e., Welcome to TeX.SX and that’s it), I think it is sometimes useful. I.e., what do you say to new users who start discussions in answers? *Without* them feeling unwelcome?

Comment: `Welcome to $SITENAME.stackexchange.com. This is a [questions and answers site](http://$SITENAME.stackexchange.com/about), not a discussion forum. To ask a new question, use the “Ask Question” button.`

Comment: If your point is that we should have `/about`, `/help/XXX`, etc. in French, I agree. But this should be separate meta threads for each topic, not one giant wall-of-text “Welcome to French.SE! By the way, by ‘Welcome’, we mean ‘read all of this before participating, there will be a test’”.

Comment: I have to point out that any such wall of text on this meta would be doubled due to its translation.

Comment: I like this idea.  Many reviewers on SO do a similar sort of thing by saying "Welcome to SO, please read about section here..." or something similar.  To be honest when I joined SE, my account was prohibited from asking questions because I didn't understand the model, even after reading the about and help sections.  Several meta posts later... I got the hang of it.  So yeah, I think this is a decent idea to at least **consider**